# Laravel 4.1 -> 4.2 breaking Query bindings

Tags: php, database, laravel, query-builder

I just upgraded to 4.2 from 4.1 and a few queries are broken. Is there a way to reqrite this query without extending anything?

This used to work fine in Laravel 4.1, but in 4.2 it does not.

```
     $stores = Store::select(
            DB::raw("id,name,
                          ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                            cos( radians( lat ) )
                            * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                            ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                            sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                          ) AS distance"))
            ->having("distance", "<", "?")
            ->orderBy("name")
            ->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat,$radius])
            ->get();
```

I tried breaking it down and got it to work if I hard code in the radius like this:

```
     $stores = Store::select(
            DB::raw("id,name,
                          ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                            cos( radians( lat ) )
                            * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                            ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                            sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                          ) AS distance"))
            ->having("distance", "<", 25)
            ->orderBy("name")
            ->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat])
            ->get();
```

Is there a new syntax I can use to fix this so I can pass in dynamic values for the radius?

Appreciate any help I can get. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
$stores = Store::select(
        DB::raw("id,name,
                      ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                        cos( radians( lat ) )
                        * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                        ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                        sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                      ) AS distance"))
        ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
        ->orderBy("name")
        ->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat])
        ->get();
```

Comment: is that safe though? I didn't want to do that as it might open up SQL injection vulnerability?

Comment: Yes definitely. All of Laravels query functions use bindings internally (except when you use the `raw` methods)

Comment: Ahhh so the having will not be executed as raw, even though it is apart of the DB raw query?

Comment: It's not really *part* of the raw query. Only the string in `DB::raw()` is the "raw" part. Everything else just works as usual. By the way you can also use `selectRaw("...")` instead of `select(DB::raw("..."))`... one pair of `()` less ;)

Comment: Awesome, sounds good mate. Thank you for the explanation. Now my code is cleaner too! Whoo hoo!